# gulp-notify: [HTML] Error Cannot read

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, gulp4

Вот такая ошибка когда я прописываю. Gulp docs , собирается папка с готовой сборкой сайта, но появляется вот такая ошибка.

gulp-notify: [HTML] Error Cannot read

Я вообще не понимаю что делать, где проблема, как найти и искать-то ее

А когда грузится страница пишет
cannot / get то есть он не может файлы найти, помогите не могу разобраться